# How to do MAX COUNT so Query returns 1 Result SQL

Tags: sql, count, max

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    EmailDomain,
    COUNT(Users) AS UserCount
FROM 
    Table_Moragn
GROUP BY 
    Id, EmailDomain
```

Which returns the following results:

| Id | EmailDomain | UserCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | @yahoo.com | 1 |
| 1 | @gmail.com | 4 |
| 2 | @hotmail.com | 1 |
| 3 | @aol.com | 1 |
| 3 | @comcast.com | 1 |

I need the Ids and the Email Domains for a later query, but I don't want multiple email domains. So I want my results to look like this:

| Id | EmailDomain | UserCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | @gmail.com | 4 |
| 2 | @hotmail.com | 1 |

Original I thought to do a Max Count either through a subquery or having by

```
SELECT
    Id,
    EmailDomain,
    COUNT(Users) AS UserCount
FROM 
    Table_Morgan
GROUP BY
    Id, EmailDomain
HAVING
    COUNT(Users) = (SELECT MAX(UserCount)
                    FROM (EmailDomain, COUNT(Users) as UserCount
                    FROM Table_Morgan
                    GROUP BY EmailDomain) AS T)
```

but I get an error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Or says it can't return multiple results with an =.

A problem I see with this in cases like ID 3, where the count is the same number.

I tried adding LIMIT at the end of my query but SQL doesn't like it.

Comment: you can use windowed function `dense_rank()` column and order by UserCount desc and  to how you want to order the email then filter by that column = 1

Comment: What about id = 3?

Comment: I don't understand how you get to that result. It seems you show one row for ID 1 (the one with a higher user count maybe?), one row for ID 2 (there is only one), no row for ID 3 (because you dislike aol and comcast?). Please explain your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dense_Rank()` windowed function to display tied rank as well.

```
SELECT   -- main result
  *
FROM (SELECT    -- ranking here
  *,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY UserCount DESC, EmailDomain) rnk
FROM (SELECT  -- group count here
  Id,
  EmailDomain,
  COUNT(Users) AS UserCount
FROM Table_Moragn
GROUP BY Id,
         EmailDomain) x) y
WHERE y.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id,
       FIRST_VALUE(EmailDomain) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY COUNT(Users) DESC) EmailDomain,
       MAX(COUNT(Users)) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) UserCount
FROM Table_Moragn
GROUP BY Id, EmailDomain;
```